# C# - Why is my form minimizing when playing 2 sounds?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a issue : I have a main form who plays music when loaded : and I made a function who plays a sound when a button is pressed : the next form is minimized and their content too (from config.cs to every form), it's supposed to be at fullscreen and I want to keep it fullscreen and not minimized when playing a sound.

Code :

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Poker
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        [DllImport("wmp.dll")]
        static extern Int32 mciSendString(string command, StringBuilder buffer, int bufferSize, IntPtr hwndCallback);
        //LoadForm lform = new LoadForm();
        Config config = new Config();
        Settings settings = new Settings();


        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    player1.PlayLooping();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
                        "Impossible de jouer le morceau.",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }).Start();
        }

        private void btnJouer_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnClick();
            this.Hide();
            config.Show();
        }
```

Sound function :

```cs
void btnClick()
        {
            new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var _bt = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
                    _bt.Open(new System.Uri(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\sfx\\button.wav"));
                    _bt.Play();
                }
                catch(Exception xe)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(xe.Message,
                        "Impossible de jouer ce son.",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                
            }).Start();
            
        }
```

Main form code :

```cs
namespace Poker
{
    partial class Main
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Main));
            this.titre = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.btnQuitter = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnJouer = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnPara = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.titre.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // titre
            // 
            this.titre.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.titre.AutoSize = true;
            this.titre.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.titre.ColumnCount = 1;
            this.titre.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.titre.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.titre.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
            this.titre.Controls.Add(this.label1, 0, 0);
            this.titre.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.titre.Name = "titre";
            this.titre.RowCount = 1;
            this.titre.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.titre.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            this.titre.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 300);
            this.titre.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 36F, ((System.Drawing.FontStyle)((System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold | System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline))), System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
            this.label1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(225, 100);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Poker";
            this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // btnQuitter
            // 
            this.btnQuitter.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.btnQuitter.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnQuitter.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 16F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnQuitter.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnQuitter.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(258, 754);
            this.btnQuitter.Name = "btnQuitter";
            this.btnQuitter.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1361, 95);
            this.btnQuitter.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btnQuitter.Text = "Quitter";
            this.btnQuitter.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnQuitter.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnQuitter_Click);
            // 
            // btnJouer
            // 
            this.btnJouer.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.btnJouer.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnJouer.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 16F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnJouer.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnJouer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(258, 489);
            this.btnJouer.Name = "btnJouer";
            this.btnJouer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1361, 95);
            this.btnJouer.TabIndex = 4;
            this.btnJouer.Text = "Jouer";
            this.btnJouer.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnJouer.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnJouer_Click_1);
            // 
            // btnPara
            // 
            this.btnPara.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.btnPara.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnPara.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 16F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnPara.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnPara.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(258, 621);
            this.btnPara.Name = "btnPara";
            this.btnPara.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1361, 95);
            this.btnPara.TabIndex = 5;
            this.btnPara.Text = "Paramètres";
            this.btnPara.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnPara.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnPara_Click);
            // 
            // Main
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("$this.BackgroundImage")));
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1046);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnPara);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnJouer);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnQuitter);
            this.Controls.Add(this.titre);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.Name = "Main";
            this.Text = "Poker";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Main_Load);
            this.titre.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.titre.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel titre;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnQuitter;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnJouer;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnPara;
    }
}
```

Target form : (config.cs)

```
namespace Poker
{
    partial class Config
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(525, 270);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(113, 65);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Config
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Name = "Config";
            this.Text = "Configuration";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Config_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary code in the question. Please try to create a [repro].

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you creating a new thread, and the Program process switches to the second thread.

How to solve: Create one object of MediaPlayer, and switch a song, when you need.
Or: Create two separated MediaPlayers and pause one when you need.

Comment: I don't want to pause : I want to play the button sound when clicked with the music

Comment: Ok, just create the second player object and don't stop the first.